# Failed to deploy sst app due to dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, sst, serverless-stack

I am new to aws and react. I had some code working yesterday (I could put data into a dynamodb table from a React page). Today I tried to create a new table (called Events), but I did not get it to work. I then rolled back all local changes using the git command 'git reset --hard' and deleted the table 'Events' from aws management system. Now I am unable to deploy the app when I run 'npx sst start'. The error message can be seen below:

```
C:\Users\nickl\padel\notes>npx sst start
Using stage: admin
Preparing your SST app

=======================
 Deploying debug stack
=======================

Deploying stacks

 ✅  admin-notes-debug-stack (no changes)


Stack admin-notes-debug-stack
  Status: no changes
  Outputs:
    BucketArn: arn:aws:s3:::admin-notes-debug-stack-bucket83908e77-1tywtvoiarr1e
    BucketName: admin-notes-debug-stack-bucket83908e77-1tywtvoiarr1e
    Endpoint: wss://8pi9mbv1qb.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/admin


===============
 Deploying app
===============

Deploying stacks
Checking deploy status...
admin-notes-storage | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | admin-notes-storage | User Initiated
admin-notes-storage | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | admin-notes-storage | Export admin-notes-storage:ExportsOutputRefEventsTable4B7491D3C6BE5608 cannot be deleted as it is in use by admin-notes-api
Checking deploy status...
admin-notes-storage | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | admin-notes-storage
admin-notes-storage | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | admin-notes-storage

 ❌  admin-notes-storage failed: Export admin-notes-storage:ExportsOutputRefEventsTable4B7491D3C6BE5608 cannot be deleted as it is in use by admin-notes-api


Stack admin-notes-storage
  Status: failed
  Error: Export admin-notes-storage:ExportsOutputRefEventsTable4B7491D3C6BE5608 cannot be deleted as it is in use by admin-notes-api

Stack admin-notes-api
  Status: not deployed

Stack admin-notes-auth
  Status: not deployed

Stack admin-notes-frontend
  Status: not deployed

Failed to deploy the app
```

Let me know if you need anything else from the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solution was to delete all stacks from the aws management system, and then recreating them.